# Approximation of certain continuous functions by analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let  $f\in C(S^{1},M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ be a unitary. Does there exist an analytic unitary function $g$ from $S^{1}$ to $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ that approximates $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by an analytic function on an arbitrary compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: In the future, if a question of yours is closed and you come up with a version of the question you believe is more appropriate, please do not post a new question. Instead edit the original question and ask users to reopen your question, either here or on chat. I have reopened this question for you, since your edit makes the question answerable.

Comment: If this question is too difficult, you can ignore the unitary condition. I want to know whether a matrix-valued continuous function can be approximated by analytic ones or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can approximate continuous functions by analytic ones (in the $\sup$ norm) on a compact. There is no difference whether are they ℝ-valued, vector-valued, or matrix-valued, as long as “analytic” denotes analyticity over ℝ not anything stronger. What means “unitary function”, simply $S^1 \to {\mathrm U}(n)$? You can approximate it as well, because U($n$) is not very different from ℝ<sup>$n^2$</sup> in this context. Does your “analytic function from the circle to U($n$)” denote merely a real-analytic function on the circle? AFAIK in this context functions that a holomorphic on the closed unit complex disc are usually considered.